# Method level custom constraint not fired on Spring controller REST method

Tags: java, spring-boot, constraints

I'm creating a custom method level constraint for a Spring REST method but the validator is not being triggered at all. The `isValid` method is never called.

```
//
// Controller
//

@PostMapping("/{id}")
@DTOParametersMatch
public ResponseEntity<DTO> createDTO(
    @PathVariable("id") @SuppressWarnings("unused") UUID id,
    @Validated(CreateValidation.class) @RequestBody DTO dto
) {
  System.out.println("***** createDTO called");
  DTO created = dtosService.createDTO(dto);
  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(created);
}


//
// DTOParametersMatch
//

@Constraint(validatedBy = DTOParametersMatchValidator.class)
@Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface DTOParametersMatch {

  String message() default "DTO ID in path must match DTO ID in body";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}


//
// DTOParametersMatchValidator
//

@SupportedValidationTarget(PARAMETERS)
public class DTOParametersMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DTOParametersMatch, Object[]> {

  private static final String ILLEGAL_ARGS_BASE =
      "Illegal usage of DTOParametersMatch; "
          + "requires two parameters where first is a UUID and second is a DTO.";

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Object[] values, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    System.out.println("***** DTOParametersMatchValidator isValid called");

    var pathId = (UUID)v0;
    var body = (DTO)v1;

    return pathId.equals(body.getId());
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I missed something or set it up wrong..

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues pointed out I was missing the `@Validated` annotation on the controller class. Once I added that, everything worked.